# Toggle Class on Single Link?

Tags: jquery, toggle, removeclass

For the purpose of a mobile navigation button, i want the link to click (show menu) add active class and then, when you click the SAME link again (collapse menu) it removes the class.

```
$(function() {  
    $(".nav-mobile").click(function () {
        $(".nav-mobile").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

This adds the active class on click, but doesn’t remove it when clicked again.

Is it possible to remove it?

Comment: it seems that it is meaningless script. you have removed a class and add it again!

Comment: The link opens a menu, i want the class to indicate the menu is open by changing its colour, you then click to close it again and its not that colour, hence not open.

Comment: You are adding it again after the remove

Comment: Is code is okay, he has multiple buttons. When he click on button 1, it add class to button 1. Then when he click on button 2, it remove class of button 1 and add class to button 2. The problem is that when he click on button 2 again, he want to remove the class of button 2, which doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `toggleClass()` function in jQuery. It does exactly what you want.

Check the api doc: https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfect. I tried toggle before and it didn’t work, does from that example.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code instead :

```
$(function() {  
    $(".nav-mobile").click(function () {
        $(".nav-mobile").not(this).removeClass("active");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function() {
    $(".nav-mobile").click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if( $this.hasClass('active')) {
            $this.removeClass('active');
        } else {
            $(".nav-mobile").removeClass("active");
            $this.addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```